# `fold` values into a HashMap

Tags: rust

After reading this article [Learning Programming Concepts by Jumping in at the Deep End](https://deterministic.space/learn-programming-jump-in-at-the-deep-end.html) I can't seem to understand how exactly `fold()` is working in this context. Mainly how `fold()` knows to grab the `word` variable from `split()`.

Here's the example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn count_words(text: &str) -> HashMap<&str, usize> {
    text.split(' ').fold(
        HashMap::new(),
        |mut map, word| { *map.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1; map }
    )
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1c48ef7279a947fcaba9e59ea2673386&version=stable)

Rust docs say:

> `fold()` takes two arguments: an initial value, and a closure with two arguments: an ‘accumulator’, and an element. The closure returns the value that the accumulator should have for the next iteration.

[Iterator - fold](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.58.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold)

So I get the `mut map` is the accumulator and I get that `split()` returns an iterator and therefore `fold()` is iterating over those values but how does `fold` know to grab that value? It's being implicitly passed but I cant seem to wrap my head around this. How is that being mapped to the `word` variable...

Not sure if I have the right mental model for this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how does `fold` know to grab that value?

`fold()` is a *method* on the iterator. That means that it has access to `self` which is the actual iterator, so it can call `self.next()` to get the next item (in this case the word, since `self` is of type [`Split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Split.html), so its `next()` does get the next word). You could imagine `fold()` being implemented with the following pseudocode:

```
fn fold<B, F>(mut self, init: B, mut f: F) -> B
where
    Self: Sized,
    F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B,
{
    let mut accum = init;
    while let Some(x) = self.next() {
        accum = f(accum, x);
    }
    accum
}
```

Ok, the above is not pseudocode, it's the [actual implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cbaeec14f90b59a91a6b0f17fc046c66fa811892/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs#L2160).

Comment: Ah! So `word` in `|mut map, word|` isn't necessarily passing `word` into the closure but rather accessing the value to then use it in the closure body i.e. `*map.entry(word)`?

Comment: @se432 I think so, yes. From `fold`'s vantage point, the word is in `x`, and `f(accum, x)` "passes it to the closure". The closure names `accum` as `map` and `x` as `word` (because it assigns meanings to what are, for `fold`, totally abstract values) and, as you say, uses it in its body.

Comment: @se432 The things written between the pipes are the closure's parameters. For functions, parameters are written between parentheses instead (and must have explicit types).

Comment: @FrancisGagné Right! I think the fact that I'm not the caller tripped me up. Seeing the `|mut map, word|` as the parameters for the closure rather than the arguments makes this way clearer. I think that's where I was getting to (with many other words) in my previous comment.